# Error while sending notifications to multiple users using Firebase Functions

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an android blog app for which when the admin post a blog, the notifications must be sent to all the users using the app.

The problem is there is no notification sent when the admin posts the blog.
I am using nodejs and here is the code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');


    var valueObject = event.data.val();
        const titleIs = event.params.pushId;

        console.log('Title is: ', titleIs);

    const payload = {
        notification: {
                title : "New status Update",
                body: "There is a new status for you!",
                icon: "default"            
        },
    };

    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent notification: ", response.message);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error sending notification: ", error)
        });
});
```

**This is java file for the service:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingServce";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        sendNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Notification icon
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**And here is the code when the admin post the blog**

```
private void startPosting() {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Posting to Status ...");

        final String title_value = mStatusTitleEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        final String description_value = mStatusDescriptionEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_value) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(description_value)
                && mImageUri != null) {

            mProgressDialog.show();

            StorageReference mFilePath =
                    mStorage.child("Status_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            mFilePath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask
                    .TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    //DB
                    HashMap<String, String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
                    notificationData.put("from", "admin");

                    mNotificationDatabase.push().setValue(notificationData)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Added to database",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(title_value);
                    newPost.child("description").setValue(description_value);

                    newPost.child("date").setValue(System.currentTimeMillis());

                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("pushnotifications");

                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain there is a problem in your function? There could be a problem with your implementation of messaging on the client side as well.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the logs and there was no problem with the function. I have edited my question.

Comment: You're not using the options you define.  Pass them as the third argument in your call to [sendToTopic()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToTopic) : `sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options)`.  This is probably not the main problem, but inclusion of high-priority will ensure the message is delivered if the device is asleep.

Comment: Does your app receive the notification when sent to topic `pushNotifications`  from the Firebase Console?

Comment: The app doesn't receive any notification. This is what I get from the Functions log: Successfully sent notification: { messageId: 5259382823931248000 }

Comment: Have you declared `MyFirebaseMessagingService` in your AndroidManifest as shown in the [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest)?

Comment: Yes, I have declared the service MyFirebaseMessagingService in the Manifest.

Comment: If the function logs are fine and you are able to confirm that message is sent, it might be you're not receiving it in FirebaseMessagingService or your notification is not notifying you. Try logging out some message in your FirebaseMessagingService to see if you indeed receive it.

Comment: Also, check if the devices are subscribed to the topics, and check if the topic is available (go to Notification tab in Firebase console and type in the topic name, it should indicate if you have subscriber or topic do not exist).

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Apart from some of the corrections mentioned here, the main problem was that the "topic" was not in the list of Firebase but was created/added later on and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your use of topic name.  In the cloud function, you are publishing to `pushNotifications`.  In your app you are subscribing to topic `pushnotifications` (all lowercase).

Comment: I have fixed the typo but still no success.

Comment: Check your logcat for a warning indicating `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`